# Creating objects dynamically, what's the alternative to eval?

Tags: javascript, eval

I'm trying to create objects dynamically, using `eval(string)`. I've been unable to find an alternative to using `eval` or at least something that I could understand.

I'm looping through code that looks like the following, the string varies randomly, picked up for an array of strings which contain objects definitions.

```
llista[dia] = eval('new Accident_mortal("EP-8", 17, "accident helicopter", 1, 2, 0)');
```

From what I've read all around, using `eval` is a bad thing, but I can't figure out how else I could do this.

**EDIT**

I think Lolo's code is what I need, can I do the following?

```
var o = [  
    { clazz1: 'Accident_mortal', args: ["EP-8", 17, "accident helicopter", 1, 2, 0] },  
    { clazz2: 'Accident_mortal', args: ["B45", 101, "accident camio", 4, 3, 1] },  
    { clazz3: 'Accident_mortal', args: ["C19", 234, "accident tot terreny", 2, 1, 1] }  
}
```

Up to 9 objects inside var o, and then use the code he proposes to generate random objects from these 9 definitions.

Comment: The solution lies in how you fetch the data. How come you're fetching code as a string?

Comment: an alternative using "what" as input?

Comment: What exactly do you start off with? In other words, where does the string itself come from?

Comment: you could directly use the way you create objects instead of putting it under eval UNLESS you are NOT dynamically getting the Class Name/Function Name(as in javascript) from somewhere else....

Comment: It's an exercise to practice using objects and inheritance.
I created an array with 9 different strings, then I use this array to create 100 objects, using Math.random() to pick up the strings for the new objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can replace array of strings with array of objects, then you may try this:

```
function construct(constructor, args) {
    function F() {
        return constructor.apply(this, args);
    }
    F.prototype = constructor.prototype;
    return new F();
}

// objects definitions
var o = [
    { clazz: 'Accident_mortal', args: ["EP-8", 17, "accident helicopter", 1, 2, 0] }
]
// create objects
for (var i = 0; i < o.length; ++i) {
    var x = construct(window[o[i].clazz], o[i].args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, though not necessarily an improvement, would be to create the `Function` constructor to eval the string, and return the new object.

```
//                    |---create a new Function
llista[dia] = (new Function( 'return ' + my_string_array[0] ))();
//                   invoke the new Function-------------------|
```

But this may prove to be desirable if you need to `eval` any of these strings more than once.

You could overwrite each member of the array with the new function.

```
for( var i = 0; i < my_string_array; ++i ) {
    my_string_array[ i ] = new Function( 'return ' + my_string_array[ i ] );
}
```

Now you can reference each item in the array as a function that returns an object created from the constructor with the given arguments.

```
 // create two objects given the same arguments
var obj_1 = my_string_array[ 2 ]();
var obj_2 = my_string_array[ 2 ]();
```

Ultimately the best solution would be to not have to work with Strings that need to be eval'd into code. If this is unavoidable, your options are limited.

Comment: My knowledge about Javascript is quite thin yet, Strings seem to be the easiest way, I just don't know any other way to do it :)